# Can not link libuuid when using CMake toolchain file to cross-compile Azure IoTHub SDK

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I don't know how to write CMake toolchain-file properly to build Azure IoTHub SDK v1.2.10 successfully.

This is my command:

```
azure-iot-sdk-c/build_all/linux# ./build.sh --no-amqp --no-http --no_uploadtoblob --no-logging --toolchain-file mytoolchain.cmake
```

And here is the build result, ld cannot find -luuid:

```
Scanning dependencies of target iothub_convenience_sample
[ 69%] Building C object iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/CMakeFiles/iothub_convenience_sample.dir/iothub_convenience_sample.c.o
[ 70%] Building C object iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/CMakeFiles/iothub_convenience_sample.dir/__/__/__/certs/certs.c.o
[ 71%] Linking C executable iothub_convenience_sample
/usr/local/bin/compile_tool/arm-2010q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/CMakeFiles/iothub_convenience_sample.dir/build.make:128: recipe for target 'iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/iothub_convenience_sample' failed
make[2]: *** [iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/iothub_convenience_sample] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1327: recipe for target 'iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/CMakeFiles/iothub_convenience_sample.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [iothub_client/samples/iothub_convenience_sample/CMakeFiles/iothub_convenience_sample.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Below is my toolchain-file:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)    
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)    

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/local/bin/compile_tool/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/bin/compile_tool/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++)

# set OpenSSL path
SET(OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY /myspace/application/openssl/libssl.so)
SET(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY /myspace/application/openssl/libcrypto.so)
SET(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /myspace/application/openssl/include)

# I can use INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES to find uuid.h
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/myspace/application/libuuid/include)
# But I can't link libuuid by setting CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH... Why?
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /myspace/application/libuuid/lib)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

I've downloaded libuuid sources and built it into `/myspace/application/libuuid/lib/`:

```
root@my-pc:/myspace/application/libuuid/lib# ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63258 十一  9 13:57 libuuid.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   953 十一  9 13:57 libuuid.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 十一  9 13:57 libuuid.so -> libuuid.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 十一  9 13:57 libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 41893 十一  9 13:57 libuuid.so.1.0.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 十一  9 13:57 pkgconfig
```

However, if I manually copy **libuuid.so.1** and **libuuid.so.1.0.0** to the path within my cross-compiler(`/usr/local/bin/compile_tool/arm-2010q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib`), it can successfully link libuuid.

So, I think there must be something wrong in my toolchain-file. I've tried to use **CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS**, **CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS**, **link_directories**, and **link_libraries**, all of above failed.

I hope somebody can teach me how to improve my toolchain-file. Thanks!

PS. I don't want to modify Azure IoTHub sources in order to keep it unchanged and easy to maintain.

Comment: As far as I understand your case, `link_directories(/myspace/application/libuuid/lib)` should work. A variable `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` which you set in your toolchain affects only on CMake searching (`find_library`), but doesn't affect on the linker itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for replying. I've tried link_directories, it seems no effect. Now I post the issue on GitHub of Azure IoT SDK to make sure whether it is the bug in SDK or not.   Here is the link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/704

Answer (score 0):

I have installed compiled libuuid library in cross compiler default path. I use `aarch64-linux-gnu` so default path will be `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/`